# Are there any custom scrollers that work inside lightboxes?

Tags: jquery, shadowbox

I am using Shadowbox and Flexcroll and cannot get them to play nice.  My shadowbox open's just fine, and the scrollbar loads but doesn't scroll.

```
Shadowbox.open({
 content: '#inline-'+myBox,
 player: 'inline',
 height: 453,
 width: 354,
 options:{
  onFinish: serviceCheck
 }      
});
```

mybox just opens the current #id...

I ahve also tested the scroller on the page without the shadowbox and it works fine.  Anyone had to implement the two, or is there another scrollbar solution that works.  I hate doing custom scrollbars...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using **Shadowbox** in conjuction with **[jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html)**?